# Check if a string contains duplicates using std::map

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I have a function that checks if a string contains duplicates using std::map by putting each char as a key. Can't figure out why this doesn't work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
int unique_char(std::string s){
 for(int i=0 ; i < s.size(); i++ )
  {
    std::map<char,int> uniq_hash_table;
    std::pair<std::map<char,int>::iterator,bool> ret;
    ret = uniq_hash_table.insert(std::pair<char,int>(s[i],0));
    if(ret.second==false)
     {
      std::cout << "The string contains duplicates" << std::endl;
      return 1;
     }
  }
return 0;
}
int main()
{
 std::string s="abcd";
 std::string s1="aabc";
 if(unique_char(s)==0){
 std::cout << "The 1st string does not contain duplicates" << std::endl;}
 if(unique_char(s1)==0){
 std::cout << "The 2nd string does not contain duplicates" << std::endl;}
 return 0;
}
```

The program returns "string does not contain duplicates" for both examples.

ps: I'm purposely using std::map to get O(n) solution.

Comment: "uniq_hash_table" is an extraordinarily misleading name...

Comment: Why do you use a map when all you seem to need is a set?

Comment: Sadly I believe that's the assignment. We had another asker through this afternoon with a similar assignment. The other asker had to implement the hash table though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because your `std::map<char,int>` is re-created at each iteration of the loop. Then, at each iteration of the loop, the map is empty. Then, there is no duplication.

Better to use a `std::set<char>`. You can do something like that :

```
bool contains_duplicated_char(const std::string& s)
{
  std::set<char> check_uniq;
  for(unsigned long int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    if(!check_uniq.insert(s[i]).second)
      return true; // Duplicated char found
  return false; // No duplicated char found
}
```

and then call it by this way :

```
const std::string str = "abcdefghijklamnopb";
const bool dupl = contains_duplicated(str);
```

In order to make your code more generic (managing more data types), you can also create your function in that way :

```
template <typename Type, typename IteratorType>
bool contains_duplicated(IteratorType begin, IteratorType end)
{
  std::set<Type> check_uniq;
  for(IteratorType it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    if(!check_uniq.insert(*it).second)
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

and then call it like :

```
std::vector<std::string> vec_str;
vec_str.push_back("Foo");
vec_str.push_back("Bar");
vec_str.push_back("Baz");
vec_str.push_back("Bar");
const bool dupl = contains_duplaicated<std::string>(vec_str.begin(), vec_str.end());
//...
const std::string str = "abcdefab";
const bool dupl2 = contains_duplacated<char>(str.begin(), str.end());
//...
const std::deque<long int> x(4, 0);
x[0] = 1;
x[1] = 17;
x[2] = 31;
x[3] = 0;
const bool dupl3 = contains_duplicated<long int>(x.begin(), x.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because `uniq_hash_table` is recreated for each symbol inside `for` loop.

Try to move it into the beginning of the function right before the `for` loop:

```
std::map<char,int> uniq_hash_table;

for(int i=0 ; i < s.size(); i++ )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oups that's true. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As your map definition is within the body of the for loop, you recreate an empty map at each iteration.

Declare your container outside the loop and it 'll work better.

Note that you could use a set instead of a map if you never increment the int value.

Comment: Thanks, that works, I am using std::map on purpose as I will count the number of duplicates next.

Comment: @b_mery ok! I was just wondering why you didn't go for an uniq_hash_table[s[i]]++ and bothered to insert a 0.